# Android - XML parsing - working on emulator but not on device

Tags: android, xml, dom, xml-parsing

In my app I'm parsing an xml, piece of structure doing problems:

```html
<answers>
    <answer value="A">A</answer>
    <answer value="B">B</answer>
    <answer value="C">C</answer>
</answers>
```

I'm parsing it with XML DOM:

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

that works great and depending on answer items I'm creating a RadioButtons like this:

```java
NodeList answers = doc.getElementsByTagName("answers").item(0).getChildNodes();

int j = 0;
RadioGroup group = new RadioGroup(this);
RadioButton button1 = new RadioButton(this);
button1.setId((i+1)*100+(j++));
button1.setText(answers.item(1).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
button1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

RadioButton button2 = new RadioButton(this);
button2.setId((i+1)*100+(j++));
button2.setText(answers.item(2).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
button2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

RadioButton button3 = new RadioButton(this);
button3.setId((i+1)*100+(j));
button3.setText(answers.item(3).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
button3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

This piece of code works perfectly in the emulator, SDK v.7 (Android 2.0), while my HTC Desire runs on Android 2.1u1 (so SDK v.8)

But in the device I get error on this line `button2.setText(answers.item(2).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());` guessing that there is no `.item(2)` in answers - but it has to be... I was debugging this code within emulator and found out that `answers.item(0)` is a `TextNode` containing the name of the XML node "answers"...

But it is true I'm a bit confused and everything is messing up when parsing this XML as I still have to count how deep am I and when to call what index on which element (node)... But still I found this implementation much simpler than using `SAX`...

Isn't there something simillar to `SimpleXml` from PHP in Java???

Anyway, my main problem is: how is it possible that application is working perfectly in emulator while on device it throws `NullPointerException` on the line where I try to set text for button2???

Many thanks for You help!!!

Comment: Oh, and when I was outputting the setText() value directly on the devicem, `button1.setText(answers.item(1).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());` was processed without error and the value was outputted while the next item `button2.setText(answers.item(2).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());` throwed an error... Therefore I do not understand it at all...

Comment: My advice: Stop using document builder to parse XML in Android, use the Simple Library instead (http://simple.sourceforge.net/) and here is a blog post on it (http://massaioli.homelinux.com/wordpress/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/)

Comment: @RobertMassaioli: Hmm, I looked at it, it looks nice, but still not very simple - You have to write and define a Class for EVERY "object" in XML (so for every TAG) - where is the simplification??? Yeah, maybe when parsing XML, it's simpler, but You have to generate maybe two times more code... BUT - I'll give it a try when there's some time left...

Comment: @shadyyx This is not true, you do not need to write a class for every tag. Take a look at the path annotation in Simple, it allows you to map multiple nested XML elements and attributes using XPath expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getChildNodes() returns all `Node`s under answers, not just all `Element`s.  You probably want to iterate through all of the children and check if each is an `Element` with tag name "answer"

How about something like this:

```
NodeList answers = doc.getElementsByTagName("answer");
for (int x = 0; x < answers.getLength(); x++) {
  Node answer = answers.get(x);
  // you could do some checking here, make sure Node is instanceof Element, etc.
  RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
  radioButton.setId((i+1)*100+(x));
  radioButton.setText(node.getNodeValue());
  radioButton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
  // add the radio button to some view
}
```

That way you aren't dependent on a particular number of child elements of answers, and you guarantee you won't try to access one that doesn't exist.

If you really want to do it based on the children of an Answers node,

```
Node answersNode = // get the node
NodeList childNodes = answersNode.getChildNodes();
for (int x = 0; x < childNodes.getLength(); x++) {
  Node node = childNodes.get(0);
  if (node instanceof Element && node.getNodeName().equals("answer")) {
    // do the same as above to create a radio button.
  }
}
```

Comment: "That way you aren't dependent on a particular number of child elements of answers, and you guarantee you won't try to access one that doesn't exist." - that's true and I know about this solution, but there always will be just and only three answer elements in each answers element, so I know that just and only three RadioButtons have to be created. Anyway, thank You for Your help, especially for the part of checking for tag name - this didn't ever come to my mind... I figured the problem out in different way and the problem was mainly in the PHP script ... (continuing in next comment)

Comment: ... generating the XML - I was using `\n` to separate the lines that generates one more TextImpl node containing `\n\n\n\n` **in emulator** that was not present (somehow) in the real device... After deleting of each `\n` from the PHP script the parsing works the same way in emulator as in the real device... I did +1 for the post, but cannot mark it as answer as I figured it out elsewhere and differently... But thank You!!!

Comment: That sounds pretty brittle.. Whitespace should not affect how the xml is parsed.  Even if you always have exactly 3 radio buttons, its still cleaner to loop through than to assume they exist at some index.

Answer (score 0):

Use (Simple XML)[http://simple.sourceforge.net/]

```
@Root
public class Answers {

   @ElementMap(entry="answer", key="value" attribute="true" inline=true)
   public Map<String, String> map;
}
```

Or if you only have three entries you could do.

```
@Root
public class Answers {

   @Path("answer[1]")
   @Text
   private answerValue1;

   @Path("answer[2]")
   @Text
   private answerValue2;

   @Path("answer[3]")
   @Text
   private answerValue3;

   @Path("answer[1]")
   @Attribute(name="value")
   private answerAttribute1;

   @Path("answer[2]")
   @Attribute(name="value")
   private answerAttribute2;

   @Path("answer[3]")
   @Attribute(name="value")
   private answerAttribute3;
}
```

Then read like so.

```
Persister persister = new Persister();
Answers answers = persister.read(Answers.class, xml);
```

Simple as that!!